# Load third party license in JNLP Web start Application

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a JNLP application that is executed from Java Web start applications. The application uses eParaksts digital signature. All the required jars are loaded and signed. They work properly. However, the jnlp requires certain eParaksts licenses to be configured in the class path as they are read by the third party libraries.

When the JNLP is executed as standalone, it is able to read classpath files mentioned in the config folder but unable to read when executed using web start. How can I make my JNLP read this files?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say

> When the JNLP is executed as standalone ...

You meant, when the application is run as a standalone Java application?

Java Web Start application cannot work with configuration folder/files the way a regular Java app does (see section [resources Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources)). If these eParaksts licenses are files, put them in a jar and deploy it as a JNLP resource. They should be then in the classpath of the application.